# Can't connect wordpress 4.5.1 to MySQL 5.7.12

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Please help. I am failing to connect `MySQL 5.7.12` database to `Wordpress 4.5.1`. Whenever I try to connect, I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1522

Comment: What is your PHP version ? It looks like a php error...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the following in your wp-config.php file?

```
define( 'WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL', true );
```

If so, comment it out.

That setting forces use of the "old" (deprecated) library for connecting to MySQL, you don't want that.